Expo Notifications in foreground does not trigger function in my apk build
I use native notify to get notifications and they work perfectly in the background. But when I am inside the app and send myself a notification, nothing happens. It should trigger my function onRefresh(), as it does when I get the notification in background.
 useEffect(() => { (async () => 
{ const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync(); 
if (status !== 'granted') 
{ alert('Permission for notifications not granted!'); 
} })(); }, []);

useEffect(() => { Notifications.setNotificationHandler({ handleNotification: async () => ({ shouldShowAlert: true, shouldPlaySound: true, shouldSetBadge: false, }), });



notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
  console.log('Notification received in foreground:', notification);
  setNotification(notification);
  onRefresh();
});

responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
  console.log('Notification response received:', response);
  onRefresh();
});

return () => {
  if (notificationListener.current) {
    Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
  }
  if (responseListener.current) {
    Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
  }
};}, []);`

I expect the notification to trigger my  onRefresh(), when inside my app
